# Use the date picker to display date ranges - as opposed to picking

Tags: reactjs, react-dates

Is there any way to use the date picker to simply display blocked out date ranges as opposed actually allowing the user to pick date ranges.

A good example of the functionality I require is the availability display that Airbnb use for each property:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Sr0B.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solved this now. In the end, I did the following:

```js
import { DayPickerSingleDateController } from 'react-dates';

....
const [focusedInput, setFocusedInput] = useState('startDate');

<DayPickerSingleDateController
...
 onFocusChange={focusedInput => {
        return true;         
   }} 
...
>
```